# Laptop slow when closing the lid

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, performance, thunderbolt

I recently bought a **MSI prestige 14-a10sc-067xes** which has:

- 16GB RAM
- 1TB SSD
- GeForce GTX 1650 4GB
- And the important thing about this - 2 thunderbolt 3 ports

The laptop is an absolute beast, it works super well and super fast for everything **BUT**

I have 2 screens:

- Philips 342B 34" UltraWide curved
- Lenovo thinkvision blabla 23" normal

I have this 2 monitors connected to 1 hub which has 2 hdmi connections in and 1 type-c thunderbolt out; the hub admits a max of 2 FHD monitors at 60hz, so we're good in this, both monitors are FHD and the philips admits 75hz but I have it configured to 60hz

**The problem** is that if I have the lid of the laptop open, everything works fine, everything goes super fast and all, BUT, in the moment I close the lid it starts going EXTREMELY slow, super bad, like to open just the browser it takes 10-20 seconds when normally it takes 1-2, when I write it goes with lag, I don't know, everything goes extremely bad, but in the moment I open the lid again everything starts to go super fast and super good again.
In the configuration I have selected to do **nothing** when the lid is closed AND I have all my drivers and all the windows updates up to date, I have windows 10 pro completely legal and everything is well configured, I don't know why is this happening.

I've been searching and people say that sometimes disabling the fast startup for any reason works but nothing. I don't know what's happening, and is only with this PC because I have other laptop (older) from the work and with this doesn't happen, this works exactly the same when is the lip open or closed, so I don't have any idea of where's the problem.

I have also called MSI technical service and they don't know what could happen either, anyone of you have any clue?

Thank you very much in advance, any information you need just ask for it

Kind regards to everyone!

Comment: Does the energy report created by `powercfg -energy` has different entries if the lid is open or closed?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the integrated graphics being used as the default or as it is a laptop automatically going into power saving mode when the lid is closed. An option, as seen on Toms Hardware ([Possible solution](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/laptop-graphic-performance-seriously-decreased-when-laptop-is-closed.369823/)) is to startup your LT with the lid closed and enter the BIOS and disable the Power Saving Mode (not sure of your BIOS but should not be difficult to find out where the setting is by checking your BIOS version and looking up how/where to find it).

Not sure if this will fix it, but worth a try I guess.